# Not able to access spreadsheet created with google api, it shows private

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Successfully got spreadsheet I'd from api call
I got spreadsheetId but couldn't
access spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Using google apps script to access spreadsheet using spreadsheet id display on dialog

```
function sendSms() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let html='';
  vs.forEach(r=>{
    html+='<br />'+r.join(',');
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Testing');
}
```